Dividing two float columns using absolute in a CASE statement returns a rounded value instead of raw value in Oracle
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ip.pricing_vol != 0 
            THEN ABS((ate.para_position / ip.pricing_vol)) 
            ELSE 0 
    AS price, 
    ip.start_date, ip.end_date
FROM 
    ab_tran_event ate, ins_price ip

para_position and pricing_vol are float columns with a data length of 22
The returned price value is rounded to no decimal places.  I have tried using to_char against the case statement, but I get the missing expression error.

your CASE expression has no END to terminate it.

Are you sure you want to work with float columns in your database? This is very unusual, as floats are not precise numbers and something as simple as a comparisons like pricing_vol != 0 can suddenly fail, because the column holds the approximate value 0.0000000000001 or the like.

@ThorstenKettner A FLOAT is a sub-type of NUMBER (and is represented internally as a NUMBER and is precise). Are you thinking of BINARY_FLOAT (which is an 32-bit floating point number and is not precise)?

@MT0: Oops. Thank you for the correction. I didn't know that Oracle's FLOAT is not the typical binary float. The mere data type name had me jump to conclusions :-)

@bimini07: If you don't see the digits, it doesn't necessarily mean they are not there. Maybe it is your database tool suppressing them when displaying the values.

@ThorstenKettner Yes, you are right. I think it's the database tool suppressing values when displaying them.  Nothing else makes sense.

Bad habits to kick: using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 30 years ago!) and its use is discouraged

SELECT ROUND(CASE WHEN ip.pricing_vol != 0 
                THEN ABS((ate.para_position / ip.pricing_vol)) 
                ELSE 0
             END ) AS price
    ,ip.start_date
    ,ip.end_date
FROM ab_tran_event ate, ins_price ip


This will round the price to the nearest whole number. If you wanted
to round to a certain number of decimal places, you could add that as
a second argument to the ROUND function. For example, ROUND(column, 2)
would round to two decimal places.

SELECT ROUND( CASE WHEN ip.pricing_vol != 0 
                    THEN ABS((ate.para_position / ip.pricing_vol)) 
                    ELSE 0 
              END, 2 ) AS price 
        ,ip.start_date
        ,ip.end_date
FROM ab_tran_event ate, ins_price ip

